# One to one function in R to change number to text

Tags: r, function

I have quite long list of postal codes with corresponding name of city or town. I just want to write a R program that has postal code as input variable and returns the name of the location (city or town). The list will be finite in length and has about 40 different pairs of postal code and location name. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
myProg<-function(code) db$city[db$code==code]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a filtering question. There are a number of ways to filter data in R. Here's what you need to do:

1. Put your data in a data.frame
2. Try filtering it:
3. Now make it a function (this is your program)
4. Use the function

`postal_codes <- data.frame(code = c(78754, 84606), location = c("Austin", "Provo"))`
`postal_codes[postal_codes$code %in% 78754, ]`

```
postal_finder <- function(mycode) {
  postal_codes$location[postal_codes$code %in% mycode]
}
```

`postal_finder(78754)`